# Gzipped content expected

Tags: php, firefox, compression, gzip

I enabled gzip compression on my website, and tested with the following tools:

- http://www.whatsmyip.org/http_compression/
- http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php
- http://web-sniffer.net/

Though, Firefox and all its extensions (Firebug, Yslow and Google Page Speed) say they receive noncompressed content.

text/html is compressed by php's ob_gzhandler, which cares about headers as well.

I don't use proxy.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not really the answer you might expect, but did you try not compressing out data with PHP, but with Apache ?

This can be done use [`mod_deflate`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html).

Couple of things :

- it would mean less calculations for PHP
- it would also mean *(and that's the nicest part **;-)** )* that your CSS/JS files could be compresses to ; considering the size of those, nowadays, it might not be a bad thing to compress them...

As a sidenote : to help us figure out what's going wrong with the compression by PHP, could you give more informations ? Like the URL of your site *(if it's public)*, and some code ?

---

**EDIT now that we have the URL** : http://ego.pestaa.hu/

When I go to that page, the response's headers are as follow :

```
HTTP/1.x 200 OK
Date: Sat, 01 Aug 2009 21:53:37 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6
**Content-Encoding: gzip**
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
```

*(using firefox 3.5 with LiveHTTPHeaders extension)*

The three testing sites you indicated also say that your page is gzipped.

Did you find what the problem was ?

Are you sure this is not something coming from your browser, that would not send the following header in the request :

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

---

**EDIT after other answer**

Quote from the comments :

> the source of problem probably isn't
>   my website but my isp/browser/router.
>   One of them may decompress every
>   component before it reaches internal
>   processes.

Oh, if the problem is not your website, I think I totally mis-understood the question -- sorry about that :-( I thought you didn't know how to server gzipped content from your website.

*And I think I'm not the only one, btw*

If the problem has nothing to do with your website's configuration, then, two possibilities :

- maybe a mis-configuration of firefox ? If you go to `about:config`, what does the `network.http.accept-encoding` say ? For me, it's `gzip,deflate`
- if the problem is coming from your ISP or something like that, there's nothing anyone can do...

Comment: My hosting does not provide mod_deflate, I tried. I use minify to compress css/js. The website in question is http://ego.pestaa.hu

Comment: oh, ok :-( too bad you don't have mod_deflate :-( ; btw, I just tested the URL you gave with FF 3.5, and the page seems to be compressed just fine : using LiveHTTPHeaders, I have a "Content-Encoding: gzip
" in the response's headers

Comment: Well, all three sites you indicated in the OP show your content is gzipped ; so, I guess you found how to solve your problem :-)

Comment: No, the source of problem probably isn't my website but my isp/browser/router. One of them may decompress every component before it reaches internal processes.

Comment: It's good to see you have the content properly compressed. Still, in my network something is missing.

Comment: Sorry, I absolutly didn't understand the questio, then : I thought the problem was that your website was not served gzipped. I've edited my answer another time ^^

Comment: I wasn't sure how to ask as well, since my browser doesn't receive the content compressed, so how could I make sure if the site is gzipped. I  tried my accept-encoding with 'gzip', 'gzip, deflate' and 'gzip,deflate' as well, nothing worked. Thanks for your help, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Live Http Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829?src=api) firefox plugin in addition to the others. It opens a window showing the exact request/response headers as they go back and forward, so you know without doubt what the accept-encoding and response-encoding is.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This extension also shows that nothing is gzipped. I wonder what could cause this.

Comment: No idea, but now you know the problem's server-side. The request includes the gzip accept header, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just enabling gzip in Apache/your web server instead/as well?

Comment: In my country there are no great hosting services, and even shared hosts with mod_deflate enabled are quite expensive. I tried to enable but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

- Are you sure you're testing the same URLs with the Firefox extensions?

  - Using the ob_gzhandler in PHP will compress the output of your php pages, but YSlow and others warn you also about uncompressed css/javascript files.
- Check that the browser is sending the correct headers. A browser usually sends the "Accept-encoding: gzip" header to tell the script/webserver it accepts compressed content. The testing scripts will surely send that but your browser might not.